# How to show all dates on a PSQL running sum in a timeframe

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing this running sum using PSQL where I would like to get daily totals of users subscribed to a service. With my current query, I get the cumulative sum in dates where clients are subscribed, but I can't get to see the values of the dates where new clients are not being subscribed. I will like to have a list of all dates with the corresponding total of clients subscribed every day as shown in the example below

```
with data as (select
  date_trunc('day', userstatuslog.modified) as modified_date, 
  user.status,
  count(1)
from userstatuslog
 join user on user.id = userstatuslog.id

where 
  user.status = 'Traveling' and     
  user.type = 'II' or 
  user.type = 'III'
group by
  1, 2
)

select
  modified_date,
  sum(count) over (order by modified_date asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from data
order by
  modified_date desc
```

Current Result:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, to include entire December 1..31 2021:

```
..
select
  c.d,
  sum(data.count) over (order by c.d asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from generate_series('2021-12-01 00:00+00'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, '2021-12-31 00:00+00', '1 days') c(d)
left join data on data.modified_date = c.d
order by c.d desc;
```

I used `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` as your displayed data has a timezone spec. It should be the same type as `modified_date` really.